# MariaDB/MySQL Database Table Corrupt, Can't Repair

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a specific table that's causing issues. phpmyadmin says it's "in use".

When I try to repair:
data_members.am_page
Error    : Incorrect information in file: './data_members/am_page.frm'
error    : Corrupt

Table(s) are MyISAM

How should I proceed to try and fix this?

"Error: Got error 185 'Incompatible key or row definition between the MariaDB .frm file and the information in the storage engine. You have to dump and restore the table to fix this' from MyISAM"

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How should I proceed to try and fix this?

Comment: I think you would have to "dump and restore the table".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

First check for all running queries and possible Connections your table might use. You can do this by

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

which gives you all running queries/Connections. You can terminate a query/Connection by

```
KILL <id>;
```

After that repair your table

```
REPAIR TABLE myTable;
```

Try to run this more than once until your Status Returns as `ok`. After that

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE myTable:
```

Then you can use the table again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> MariaDB > repair table tetra2cur;
>
> Table                 | Op     | Msg_type  | Msg_text
>
> tetrawikidb.tetra2cur | repair | Error    | Got error 185 'Incompatible key or row definition between the MariaDB .frm file and the information in the storage engine. You have to dump and restore the table to fix this' from MyISAM |
>
> tetrawikidb.tetra2cur | repair | error    | Corrupt

Thus repair table doesn't help. Using 5.5.39-MariaDB

Don't how to do. Downgrading to former MariaDb versions. These are databases which I probably did not check "enough" when migrating from mysql to mariadb.
Or use mysql and mysqldump?

Comment: >  repair table tetra2cur use_frm;
>| tetra2cur | repair | error    | Failed repairing a very old .frm file as the data file format has changed between versions. Please dump the table in your old system with mysqldump and read it into this system with mysql or mysqlimport |

Thus, use_frm doesn't work either.

Comment: SOLVED by deleting this old table. The cur table is no more used (is replaced by page) in mediawiki since version 1.4 i.e 2006!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message when copying over an older database snapshot. What worked for me was running:

```
REPAIR TABLE myTable USE_FRM;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: When your tables are corrupt there are never any guarantees and ymmv. Needless to say, always make a backup before attempting a repair.